# How to post Images and Text together in facebook without intent in android?

Tags: android, android-facebook

I want Image and Text share together in Facebook through android application..... i am getting text by this method.

```
public void postToWall() {
        // post on user's wall.
        facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            }
        });

    }
```

Now ant add image together with text but want without intent functionality

Comment: Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("message", category_item_name_desc.getText().toString());
                parameters.putString("picture", categoryItemsModel.getImageUrl());
                parameters.putString("caption", txtDescription_desc.getText().toString());
                facebook.request("/me/feed", parameters, "POST");

Comment: Check : https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook